# Python SVN - outputting log messages

Tags: python, svn

I have successfully found the method to print the entire log entry:

```
import svn.remote

control = svn.remote.RemoteClient('http://10.41.10.29/svn/directory/subdirectory')
for e in control.log_default():
      pprint.pprint(e)
```

...which produces output like this:

```
LogEntry(date=datetime.datetime(2017, 5, 3, 17, 6, 3, 905705, tzinfo=tzutc()), msg='we did something to this', revision=24945, author='bob', changelist=None)
LogEntry(date=datetime.datetime(2017, 4, 10, 14, 52, 37, 145437, tzinfo=tzutc()), msg='wow another change we made', revision=24635, author='bobdrick', changelist=None)
```

...and so on. Is there any way to just output the "msg='...'" part of the entry?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out, the syntax looks like this:

```
for e in control.log_default():
      pprint.pprint(e.msg)
```

Easy fix I overlooked